# Measure Execution time of Parallel.For

Tags: c#, .net

I am using a Parallel.For loop to increase execution speed of a computation.

I would like to measure the approximate time left for the computation. Normally one simply has to measure the time it takes for each step and estimate the total time by multiplying the step time by the total number of steps.

e.g., If there are 100 steps and some step takes 5 seconds then one could except that the total time would be about 500 seconds. (one could average over several steps and continuously report to the user which is what I want to do).

The only way I can think to do this is by using an outer for loop that essentially resorts back to the original way by splitting up the parallel.for interval and measuring each one.

```
for(i;n;i += step)
    Time(Parallel.For(i, i + step - 1, ...))
```

This isn't a very good way in general because either a few number of very long steps or a large number of short steps cause problems with timing.

Anyone have any ideas?

(Please realize I need a real time estimation of the time it is taking the parallel.for to complete and NOT the total time. I want to let the user know how much time is left in execution).

Comment: This is a hard problem. See http://xkcd.com/612/

Answer (score 4):

This method seems to be pretty effective. We can "linearize" the parallel for loop by simply having each parallel loop increment a counter:

```
Parallel.For(0, n, (i) => { Thread.Sleep(1000); Interlocked.Increment(ref cnt); });
```

(Note, thanks to Niclas, that `++` is not atomic and one must use `lock` or `Interlocked.Increment`)

Each loop, running in parallel, will increment `cnt`. The effect is that `cnt` is monotonically increasing to `n`, and `cnt/n` is the percentage of how much the for is complete. Since there is no contention for `cnt`, there are no concurrency issues and it is very fast and very perfectly accurate.

We can measure the percentage of completion of the parallel `For` loop at any time during the execution by simply computing `cnt/n`

The total computation time can be easily estimated by dividing the elapsed time since the start of the loop with the percentage the loop is at. These two quantities should have approximately the same rates of change when each loop takes approximately the same amount of time is relatively well behaved (can average out small fluctuation too).

Obviously the more unpredictable each task is, the more inaccurate the remaining computation time will be. This is to be expected and in general, there is no solution (which is why it's called an approximation). We can still get the elapsed computation time or percentage with complete accuracy.

The underlying assumption of any estimation of "time left" algorithms is each sub task takes approximately the same computation time (assuming one wants a linear result). For example, if we have a parallel approach where 99 tasks are very quick and 1 task is very slow, our estimation will be grossly inaccurate. Our counter will zip up to 99 pretty quick then sit on the last percentage until the slow task completes. We could linearly interpolate and do further estimation to get a smoother countdown but ultimately there is a breaking point.

The following code demonstrates how to measure the parallel for efficiently. Note the time at 100% is the true total execution time and can be used as a reference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ParallelForTiming
{
    class Program
    {       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sw = new Stopwatch();
            var pct = 0.000001;
            var iter = 20;
            var time = 20 * 1000 / iter;
            var p = new ParallelOptions(); p.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;

            var Done = false;
            Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            {
                sw.Start();
                Parallel.For(0, iter, p, (i) => { Thread.Sleep(time); lock(p) { pct += 1 / (double)iter; }});               
                sw.Stop(); 
                Done = true;

            }, () =>
            {
                while (!Done)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(pct*100,2) + " : " + ((pct < 0.1) ? "oo" : (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / pct /1000.0).ToString()));
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }

            }
            );
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(pct * 100, 2) + " : " + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / pct / 1000.0);


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okey.. Isn't this just kind of the implementation that Alex suggested? Also, it might just be that I haven't had enough coffee this morning but are there any locks in there? It looks like you just add to a global variable without locking it first...? If you would like to do something along these lines i would use Alex's implementation instead. It's much cleaner IMO.

Comment: @Niclas It's not the same but close. He computes the time per task. must slower to do than incrementing a counter. There is no need for a lock on the counter since there is no contention. There is no possible way for the counter to become corrupt since it is a monoatomic operation. Surely you realize the sleep is just for demo purposes and is a placeholder for any general computation? You also realize my code is about 1/10 of Alex's and essentially is just adding two lines of code to the basic case? I don't see how you can say his is "cleaner" but I guess to each his own.

Comment: BTW, mine version works on a very simple principle of computing the percentage and is perfectly accurate. Alex's times each task which can be unpredictable. A task could be interrupted by another task causing it's time to be exaggerated.

Comment: Since the discussion got cleaned up (rightfully i guess) it appears that this is a correct answer to the question. It is not. This code is NOT thread-safe and shouldn't be used by anyone looking for a solution to this problem. Consider this short example:-  
`int count = 1;  
Parallel.For(0, 20000000, (i) => { count++; });  
Console.WriteLine(count.ToString());  
Console.ReadKey();`

Comment: Your right. I was under the wrong impression that ++ was atomic for CLR. It turns out it is not. (most cpu's have an atomic increment operation) The correct answer is to use `Interlocked.Increment` instead of `++`. Other than that the code works fine(try it). Thanks for coming up with a counter example BUT it seems if you really understood what was going on you would have simply said `++` IS not atomic instead of playing games.  (after all, one could just lock on the counter. I thought this was redundant)

Comment: I did, someone removed all those comments. This was what i was after from my very first comment but i didn't had the time to look through everything line by line and were under the impression that you did something really tricky with the dual threading and sleep, and instead of just answering you started to bash me for not "knowing" what sleep was for.. That really pissed me of.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost impossible to answer.

First of all, it's not clear what all the steps do. Some steps may be I/O-intensive, or computationally intensive.

Furthermore, Parallel.For is a request -- you are not sure that your code will actually run in parallel. It depends on circumstances (availability of threads and memory) whether the code will actually run in parallel. Then if you have parallel code that relies on I/O, one thread will block the others while waiting for the I/O to complete. And you don't know what other processes are doing either.

This is what makes predicting how long something will take extremely error-prone and, actually, an exercise in futility.

Comment: Oh come on, it's done all the time! Most processes are rather predictable in most circumstances AND it is better to have some idea than none at all. WHEN you average over many small quick steps it tends to be rather accurate. All you have done is listed the issues that I've mentioned. In my case I am computing different parts of the same mathematical function and therefor all parallel parts will execute in about the same time. It would be better to have a solution that works in some cases than none at all JUST because it might not work in all cases well.

Comment: It's done all the time, yes -- badly. Take a look at the predictions of Access, Windows file copy or the GPS in your car. This can be done reliably only if all steps of your process are very predictable and if your machine isn't doing anything else that requires signifcant resources or I/O.

Comment: Even if they are not it's better to have some idea. I'd rather have some estimate of the time a long process is going to take even if it is off by a factor of 10 than no clue to how long it will take. In any case, most stuff involving computations is rather predictable.  The main issue I have with your statements is you act like just because some things are not estimated accurately(which could probably be improved with statistical analysis and performance collecting) we are suppose to dump the whole idea or that it's bad "all the time". There for certainly cases were it is good.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a tough one to answer. The problems with timing that you refer to using very long steps or a large number of very short steps are likley related to that your loop will be working at the edges of what the parallel partitioner can handle.

Since the default partitioner is very dynamic and we know nothing about your actual problem there is no good answer that allows you to solve the problem at hand while still reaping the benefits of parallel execution with dynamic load balancing.

If it is *very* important to achive a reliable estimation of projected runtime perhaps you could set up a [custom partitioner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997411.aspx) and then leverage your knowledge about the partioning to extrapolate timings from a few chunks on one thread.

Comment: The custom partitioner seems like it would definitely solve the problem but is only one step removed from the original potential solution(using an outer for loop). I  think I have a way to do it effectively and actually quite simple but need to test it(at least in giving a percentage left but it should be rather easy to convert that to a time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution to measure the average of all previously finished tasks. After each task finishes, an `Action<T>` is called where you could summarize all times and divide it by the total tasks finished. This is however just the current state and has no way to predict any future tasks / averages. (As others mentioned, this is quite difficult)

However: You'll have to measure if it fits for your problem because there is a possibility for lock contention on both the method level declared variables.

```
     static void ComputeParallelForWithTLS()
            {
                var collection = new List<int>() { 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 }; // values used as sleep parameter
                var sync = new object();
                TimeSpan averageTime = new TimeSpan();
                int amountOfItemsDone = 0; // referenced by the TPL, increment it with lock / interlocked.increment

                Parallel.For(0, collection.Count,
                    () => new TimeSpan(),
                    (i, loopState, tlData) =>
                    {
                        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        DoWork(collection, i);
                        sw.Stop();
                        return sw.Elapsed;
                    },
                    threadLocalData =>   // Called each time a task finishes
                    {
                        lock (sync)
                        {
                            averageTime += threadLocalData; // add time used for this task to the total.
                        }
                        Interlocked.Increment(ref amountOfItemsDone); // increment the tasks done
                        Console.WriteLine(averageTime.TotalMilliseconds / amountOfItemsDone + ms."); 
/*print out the average for all done tasks so far. For an estimation, 
multiply with the remaining items.*/
                    });
            }
            static void DoWork(List<int> items, int current)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(items[current]);
            }
```

Comment: This is a really bad implementation with regard to performance as each thread will lock and have to wait for all others to access the shared variable, just to show a progress indicator. This approach is especially bad if the work is divided into many small chunks and partitioned among many different threads.

Comment: @Niclas While I agree that access to shared variables comes with a price, lock contention only happens after each task has finished its work (And only IF two or more tasks finish at the same time). So you can't broadly state that this will be a problem. You'd have to measure in your exact use case.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. Perhaps I was a bit harsh when I said it was a really bad implementation. However it is a risky implementation since you don't control the division of tasks and threading yourself. Therefore it could completely kill performance, or it could not alter it at all and there is really no way to be sure if you have a dynamic problem that could change at runtime. I wouldn't recommend this implementation without more knowledge of the problem at hand.

Comment: Since getting multi threading right is really hard, the programmer should always measure possible solutions anyway. I was merely giving an idea to use the thread local data from the TPL because you can hook into after each task is done.

Comment: Coming from a computational science background i both agree and disagree with you. Of course you should try to measure whenever you can, but the whole point of parallel.for is to lift the burden of parallelization from the programmer and therefore you have no control over how parallelization is executed and then measuring to improve becomes kind of pointless. And it gets even more pointless if the nature of the problem might change at runtime since parallel.for may have very different behavior depending on problem and even on the particular hardware - of which you can make no assumptions...

Comment: This looks like it might be an overly complex idea. I came up with something similar that I'll post as an answer since it seems to be pretty effective. (we can "linearize the parallel for loop in special way)

Comment: @Niclas Parallelization is be deterministic so regardless of how the tasks are partitioned each one has a computation time that is part of the whole. The problem with estimating the computation time *left* is a different problem AND requires that each task takes about the same computation time. Once we know the total number of tasks, the average time per task, and the current number of tasks complete it is quite simple to estimate the computation time left. See my answer for a pretty straightforward example of this.

Comment: Parallelization is NOT deterministic. That's what I have tried to point out all the time. The parallel.for partitioner is dynamic and may change it's behavior at runtime for reasons that you as a programmer has no control whatsoever over. It's also possible that the behavior changes over time as the .NET libraries evolve. You shouldn't build optimizations into your code that makes assumption on how the parallelization will be performed without explicitly controlling it. That's just bad practice...

Comment: @Niclas I'm sorry but by that statement shows that you know nothing about computation. Computers are deterministic machines. This is why RNG algorithms are not true random number generators. Just because you think it is not deterministic OR cannot determine the path a process took DOES NOT MEAN IT CAN NOT BE DONE! You seem to know very little about the internal workings of multi-threading... please stop trying to act like an expert on it.  (it's one thing to say you don't have the information to determine the outcome and something entirely different to say the process is nondeterministic)

Comment: @Niclas Just because one doesn't know the inner workings of a process does not mean that process is non-deterministic. It simply means one lacks the information to determine the output. While one could argue it is all a matter of perspective we are not talking about theoretical and/or philosophical things. The difference between `Parallel.For` and `for` is that the first partitions up the interval into pieces and then sequences those pieces(a task scheduler that is deterministic). If we know how it partitions up the pieces just have an out of order execution of the in-order from the for loop.

Comment: @Niclas There are processes that are completely non-deterministic and this is usually in the realm of chaos theory, not computer programming. Which, in fact, a computer algorithm/program can only approximate in a deterministic way.

Comment: That statement shows that you know nothing about parallel computing. Parallel computing, and race conditions such as the one you created in your own answer are widely considered to be non-deterministic.

Comment: @Niclas Nothing about parallel computing huh? You obviously don't know as much as you think... you think your some expert but couldn't even say that `++` was not atomic. Instead, I guess you spend a whole day or so trying to find some minimum example that didn't work instead of, with all your righteous intelligence, just realizing that the counter increment needed to be locked. I actually thought about it but assumed, wrongly, that it was an atomic operation... at least I have the intelligence to admit when I'm wrong instead of assuming I'm a know it all like yourself.

Comment: Okey. The first thing i asked you was "...  It looks like you just add to a global variable without locking it first...?" What part of that did you fail to understand? Instead of just asking what i meant you started to throw around expressions such as "monoatomic" that obviously don't mean anything, but i guess is supposed to mean atomic and question my knowledge of even the simplest things.. I am now leaving this discussion as we can argue about this for hours and none will get happier or smarter from that..

Answer (score 0):

I would propose having the method being executed at each step report when it is done. This is slightly tricky with thread safety of course, so that is something to remember when implementing. This will let you keep track of number of finished tasks out of the total, and also makes it (sort of) easy to know the time spent on each individual step, which is useful to remove outliers etc.

**EDIT:** Some code to demonstrate the idea

```
Parallel.For(startIdx, endIdx, idx => {
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    DoCalculation(idx);
    sw.Stop();
    var dur = sw.Elapsed;
    ReportFinished(idx, dur);
});
```

The key here is that `ReportFinished` will give you continuous information about number of finished tasks, and the duration of each of them. This enables you to do some better guesses about how long time remains by doing statistics on this data.

Comment: Yeah, that's the basic idea BUT one must know how many tasks will be executed and divide them up initially in the appropriate way. I was hoping someone knew how to get these results for Parallel.For.

Comment: @Archival: You do not need to divide them into chunks, I'd say (you do need to know how many there are though, otherwise it's hard to know how much is left). I'll edit in some code to show how I mean.

Comment: Well, I mean, "by divide" up is that you have to know how it is done to be able to time them. Parallel.For internally does this. I figured out that you can simply count each task and by knowing the total(which is passed to Parallel.For, it is quite easy to get the percentage completion and one can estimate the total time from that.  See my answer for a working solution(which seems to work well so far).

Answer (score 0):

Here i wrote class that mesures time and speed

```
public static class Counter
{
    private static long _seriesProcessedItems = 0;
    private static long _totalProcessedItems = 0;
    private static TimeSpan _totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
    private static DateTime _operationStartTime;
    private static object _lock = new object();
    private static int _numberOfCurrentOperations = 0;



    public static void StartAsyncOperation()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_numberOfCurrentOperations == 0)
            {
                _operationStartTime = DateTime.Now;   
            }

            _numberOfCurrentOperations++;
        }
    }

    public static void EndAsyncOperation(int itemsProcessed)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _numberOfCurrentOperations--;
            if (_numberOfCurrentOperations < 0) 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("EndAsyncOperation without StartAsyncOperation");

            _seriesProcessedItems +=itemsProcessed;

            if (_numberOfCurrentOperations == 0)
            {
                _totalProcessedItems += _seriesProcessedItems;
                _totalTime += DateTime.Now - _operationStartTime;
                _seriesProcessedItems = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public static double GetAvgSpeed()
    {
        if (_totalProcessedItems == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("_totalProcessedItems is zero");
        if (_totalProcessedItems == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("_totalTime is zero");
        return _totalProcessedItems / (double)_totalTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    public static void Reset()
    {
        _totalProcessedItems = 0;
        _totalTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
    }
}
```

Example of usage and test:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var st = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Parallel.For(0, 100, _ =>
        {
            Counter.StartAsyncOperation();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Counter.EndAsyncOperation(1);
        });

        st.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Speed correct {0}", 100 / (double)st.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.WriteLine("Speed to test {0}", Counter.GetAvgSpeed());
    }
```